# How to create LB on AWS that does not target port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancer

I have an ubuntu instance with a process listening on port 3000, exposed via security group and all that.

When I create an LB and a respective target group, and port 3000 for this TG,  the UI will *not* allow me to find any machines/instances to attach to the TG, no instances show up in the list, and certainly not the machine with the process listening on 3000. The regions and everything is fine, we have 100+ instances running in this region so something is weird.

Anyone know how to attach machines to an LB forwarding to port 3000 (anything other than 80)?

Comment: perhaps i need to use a network LB instead of application LB?

Comment: No, that's not it.  But did you place the balancer in the same *availability zone* (not just region) as the instance?  There should be no port checking done when presenting the candidate instances.  You should see many instances listed.

Comment: i see i never considered availability zones to be that important but maybe they are